# cannot access on production CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sorry this is my first time i migrate to production

Problem is The requested URL '172.16.10.251/GD/login/getLogin' was not found on this server.

at localhost is working fine and already changed
base_url change to /172.16.10.251/

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^172.16.10.251$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

thank you

Update

error message

Not Found

The requested URL /GD/login/getLogin was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) Server at 172.16.10.251 Port 80

Comment: did you change the base_url after you upload your site?

Comment: yes replace localhost to 172.16.10.251

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /yourfolder/index.php/$1 [L,QSA] did you try to put the folder on this code

Comment: @CodeSlayer still not working..fyi form server window to server linux

Comment: i don't know what version of code igniter you are using where did you get the code of RewriteRule..

Comment: im not yet uploading a site that created in ci..and in my local host
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /yourfolder/index.php/$1 [L] this is working..

Comment: me at localhost also working but when migrated to production got error.

Comment: read the user guide in your ci folder

Answer (score 0):

did you try this one..
open config folder and the database file

in `$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';`
change it to

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'your ip';
```

also use this instead
in .htaccess

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_TEST ----> activate the php 5.3

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1/ [L]
```

but if you have more than 3 apps

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_TEST ----> activate the php 5.3 //php version

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^foo(.*)$ index_foo.php/$1/ [L] //foo app, http://www.example.com/foo

RewriteRule ^bar(.*)$ index_bar.php/$1/ [L] //bar app, http://www.example.com/bar

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1/ [L]
```

but this will only work for version 2.0 and I don't know if this will work on other versions.

Comment: for $db['default']['hostname'] = 'your ip' already point to another server.

Comment: make it null $config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: ..still not working.is there any setting required for migration from dev to prod.first time migrate to prod.anyway thank you so much